# web2py/pretty ImportError: No module named proj.modules.pretty

Tags: web2py

I'm trying to import the "pretty" date module http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-pretty in my web2py application. I unzipped, extracted **init**.py and renamed it to pretty.py and placed in:`proj/modules`. I am trying to import it using: `local_import ('pretty', reload=True)`

But, I get this error: `ImportError: No module named proj.modules.pretty`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local_import` has been deprecated. You should now be able to do:

```
import pretty
```

Also, note that web2py includes its own pretty date functionality: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14#Pretty-dates

Comment: Now I get this: ImportError: No module named pretty. Thanks for the link, that should solve my immediate need for pretty dates, but I do plan on using modules, so it will be nice to figure this out.

Comment: That probably indicates an error in the pretty.py module itself. Perhaps it is trying to import a dependency that you don't have. Are you able to import it (as is, from its current location) from a standalone Python program? If not, the problem is with the module.

Comment: I created a new file called 'common.py' in the modules directory. All it contains is: 
 
 def add(a, b):
 return a+b
 
. I use import common in default.py, but I get the same error for common.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem - my application directory name was in all uppercase. Everything worked except for the import statement. Once I made it all lower-case, it started working.